# Misbehaving replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) in java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, replace, charsequence

This snippet prints ?!

```
String str = "";
str = str.replace(new StringBuilder('Z'), new StringBuilder("?!"));
System.out.println(str);    // prints ?!
```

How come?
(I'm running JSE RTE 1.8.0_66 with HotSpot x64 VM (25.66-b18) on Win7)

Comment: What do you think it should print and why? That little bit of information shows us you've done your research.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Since the object didn't contain the target sequence Z, it shouldn't have changed --- that was my initial reasoning. Apparently faulty, and now I know why :) I'm just studying for my OCP cert exam and need to play with code, that's all... Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I finally found the answer.

Contrary to the suggested explanation by *resueman*, the test

```
"".equals(new StringBuilder('Z'))
```

returns **false**, so I was *NOT* "effectively doing" `"".replace("", "?!")`. To appreciate my point better, observe that
`"_".replace("", "^")` returns **^_^** . Do find a minute to run this LOC, you'll be amused, I'm sure.

The real reason behind this seemingly odd behaviour is that the regex engine matches boundaries in empty strings...